# How can I declare my return type from generic function in generic class

Tags: c++, c++11, generics, struct

I have generic class in c++

```
template<typename A>
struct  series { 

A member;
}

template<typename A,typename B,typename C>
series <C> & operator + (A first, const B& second) {
return first+second;
}
```

I need to return type that is implicit conversion of  type A and type B.
Fox example :
double a + int b → implicit conversion is double
how can I do that, because C cannot be determined like this
I was trying something with decltype and typedef but it didn't work
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You can use C++11 trailing return types with `decltype`:

```
template<typename A,typename B>
auto operator+(A first, const B& second) -> decltype(first+second) {
  return first+second;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The standard library provides a number of templates for situations like this. For the moment, let's deal with the really simple case:

```cpp
template <class T, class U>
returnType operator+(T t, U u) {
    return t + u;
}
```

So what should we use for `returnType`? In this case, we can use `std::common_type`, which tells us the common type to which both its operand types will be converted when used in an expression together.

```cpp
template <class T, class U>
typename std::common_type<T, U>::type add(T t, U u) {
    return t + u;
}
```

So, if we passed this an `int` and a `double`, the return type would be `double`.

In most cases, the result type is pretty obvious, but in a few cases, the result can be...interesting, to put it mildly. For example, on an implementation that used 16 bits for both `short` and `int` (like many MS-DOS compilers did), it's entirely possible that `unsigned short + int` could have a common type of `long`.

Comment: as usual there is a choice to do between `std::common_type` and `decltype(t + u)` which give different result for integral type smaller than `int`.